# AWS Spark standalone cluster does not start

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2

I have an ASW EC2 node. I have installed Apache spark on the node.

I use a command like this to start the cluster:

`spark-ec2/spark-ec2 -k NAME_OF_KEY_PAIR --identity-file=PATH_TO_PEM_FILE --region=us-west-2 --zone=us-west-2a --copy-aws-credentials start NAME_OF_YOUR_CLUSTER`

When I start the cluster, I get a message like this:

> Connection to ec2-34-214-104-6.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com closed.

Spark standalone cluster started at
 http://ec2-38-218-104-6.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080.

Ganglia started at http://ec2-388-218-104-6.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:5080/ganglia.

However, there is nothing running on the URL given for the spark stand alone cluster. The Ganglia URL does work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the required ports are open in the instance ? By Default Only SSH is open that is also bound to your IP.

Try reading through this [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#vpc-security-groups)

Thanks

Comment: That was the issue! I added a rule to allow port 8080 to go through and it worked!  Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to have helped , can you mark the answer as resolved.